# Google Calendar API v3?

Tags: vb.net, google-api, google-calendar-api

Sinse Google discontinued API v2 on the 17th, my application that syncs our database to Google calendar stopped working.

Now I want to migrate to v3, however it turning out to be a lot of effort and lack of examples in vb.net code. But I managed to get some, however it isn't working and I have some questions about it.

First, the new example on the Google website explains that there using .JSON file. How can I add this to the project?

And second, this is the vb.net example code from Google, however it doesn't work:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Calendar.v3
Imports Google.Apis.Services
Imports Google.Apis.Util.Store


Public Class Form1
    Private Shared Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim credential As UserCredential
        ' This example uses the client_secrets.json file for authorization.
        ' This file can be downloaded from the Google Developers Console
        ' project.
        Using stream = New FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, New () {CalendarService.Scope.Calendar}, "user", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore("Calendar.Auth.Store")).Result
        End Using

        ' Create the service.
        Dim service = New CalendarService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {Key.HttpClientInitializer = credential, Key.ApplicationName = "Calendar API Sample" })
    End Sub
End Class
```

The compiler says, there are two error, the key. isn't recognized properly and new() isn't vailig.

I was hoping someone could help me out with this, or has a working sample v3 in vb.net

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [Calendar Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/migration). It should serve as a good reference for migrating over to v3. It also contains sample code for various languages, including .NET.

As for your errors, `New () {CalendarService.Scope.Calendar}, "user"` looks like a problem to me. The scopes for Google Calendar are:

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly`

You may want to refer to the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth). Depending on what else you do with the app, you may need other scopes as well.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I read the documenten about the migration and also the calander service however, the problem is i couldn't find any info how to apply the right syntax. Maybe i'm missing something but i couldn't find any examples that worked with the right syntax. So maybe someone could help me out with this?